# Select multiple divs for on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to select multiple ids for an on change call? I know the following code doesn't work, but this is the type of logic that I'm looking for.

```
$('#id_home_state' || '#id_home_count' ).on('change', function() {
```

Comment: With a normal research you would easily found this: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: $("#id1, #id2, #id3"), looks like inside the " and separate by ,

Comment: Thanks Cristina!